# My Javascript seems to fail on Mobile Chrome, and I'm unable to debug it on my Mac

Tags: javascript, android, macos, google-chrome

I just published an app at http://ineedaprompt.com. It relies on front-end Javascript.

It seems to work on all browsers except the somewhat-outdated version of Chrome (v. 42.0.2311.111) I have on my somewhat-outdated Android smartphone. I've never gotten USB debugging to work with my Mac, and so don't seem to have a way of debugging the Javascript for this particular browser.

This may very well be an edge case, but I'm unsure -- I think the odds are if it fails for one browser, it will fail for others.

Are there any recommendations on how I could debug this? Or might some kind-hearted person be able to check their console tell me the reason this JS is failing?

The source code is available at the links below. Since I cannot access the console, I have no idea which lines are causing the error, and so cannot include any code in this question.

https://github.com/RobertAKARobin/inap-node/blob/master/public/ineedaprompt.js
https://github.com/RobertAKARobin/inap-node/blob/master/public/index.html

Comment: What is the Error, i mean, what is the meaning of "working on all browser except chrome" means?

Comment: The Javascript visibly executes on all browsers except mobile Chrome. I can see the DOM manipulation take place.